# Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got bytes

Tags: django-rest-framework

when I request to save API, I got this error:
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got bytes."
    ]
}

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class employee(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    emo_id=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:  
        db_table = "employee" 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

```
serializer.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import employee

class convertSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = employee
        fields = '__all__' # for all field
```

---

views.py

```
def saveEmployee(request):
    serializer = convertSerializers(data=request.body)
    print(serializer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse('saved successfull', safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using DRF, you can use [**`request.data`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) instead of **`request.body`**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(['POST'])
def saveEmployee(request):
    serializer = convertSerializers(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response('saved successful')
```

Comment: may you please say why my code has error:
and what is the different?
i wrote the code based on training movie and I dont know why i got the error!!!

Comment: You were used `request.body`, it shouldn't be